# Create a shopping cart of selected items in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working with R shiny.
In the app I have a scatter plot. When you make a selection of points on the scatter plot a table (table 1) appears with information on the points selected. You can then make a selection from table 1 to display a second table (table 2) with information on the selection from table 1. I am trying to add selected items from table 2 to another table (table 3) but I want these items to remain in table 3 when new table 2s and table 1s are generated. Essentially I want to add multiple items to a "shopping cart" for download.

Is there anyway to do this in R shiny?
Below is a snip it of my server code.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
######scatter plot
output$landscape_scatter <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly(data = data, x = ~X, y = ~Y, 
                 color= ~get(input$landscape_color), 
                 type="scatter"
                 )
    p
  })
####### table 1
  output$selected.data.table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    if (is.null(d))
      return()
    x_min <- round(min(d$x), 5)-0.00001
    x_max <- round(max(d$x),5)+0.00001
    y_min <- round(min(d$y), 5)-0.00001
    y_max <- round(max(d$y), 5)+0.00001

    sel.data <- subset(data, X >= x_min &
                         X <= x_max &
                         Y >= y_min &
                         Y <= y_max)

    sel.data <- sel.data[,c(37,6,33)]
    sel.data$cluster <- as.integer(sel.data$cluster)

    table.data <- DT::datatable(sel.data[,c(4,1,2)], class = 'compact', width = "100%", rownames = FALSE, escape=c(-1), selection = c("single")
    )
    table.data
  })
###### table 2
output$data2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    if (is.null(d))
      return()
    x_min <- round(min(d$x), 5)-0.00001
    x_max <- round(max(d$x),5)+0.00001
    y_min <- round(min(d$y), 5)-0.00001
    y_max <- round(max(d$y), 5)+0.00001

    sel.data <- subset(data, X >= x_min &
                         X <= x_max &
                         Y >= y_min &
                         Y <= y_max)

    sel.data <- sel.data[,c(37,6,33)]
    sel.data$cluster <- as.integer(sel.data$cluster)

    data2 <- card[which(card$NUMBER %in% sel.data[input$selected.data.table_rows_selected,2]),c(1,3,11,14)]

    table.data <- DT::datatable(data2)
    )  
    table.data
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want the items selected from table 2 to remain in table 3 when new table 1s and table 2s are generated but when I select new points on the scatter plot to generate new table 1s all the rows/items in table 3 disappear.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide us with a full reproducible example (not only the server function).